# Upload an image with PHP using JQUERY Object

Tags: php, jquery, image, object, upload

I have an image (a captcha specifically) that I want to upload to my server using PHP (or if possible and better, only JQUERY)

I created an object with this code:

```
var newIMG = $("img[name='captchaImage']").clone();
```

But I cannot send it via jQuery's ajax method or else. (Even tried to manually add but no idea how to send an object as file)

What should be the simplest PHP / jQuery code to send this object?

Thanks in advance,

Comment: Why do you want to upload a captacha image in the first place?

Comment: You cannot *send* a jQuery-object. The simplest way would be creating a file type input and submit its data via POST.

Comment: @ Dainis Abols: Not illegal, in fact not even on www. I use it on my university dorm room computer because after a while it kicks me out of the server and before login, I'm offline.

Comment: @m90: How can I send the newIMG object as file input?

Answer (score 0):

You can use  [jsupload](https://github.com/valums/file-uploader) plugin for this purpose.

One cannot upload files using AJAX..

You can also use an iframe to simulate uploading the files..

Comment: But JS upload will require me to enter values by hand. I want to do it with the object I've loaded.

Answer (score 0):

only jquery file upload is not possible you need php

and you can use [the jQuery File Upload](http://blueimp.github.com/jQuery-File-Upload/) to upload file via ajax and jquery